# Java ssl server/client application passing byte []

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating an application in java (server / client) that uses a secure connection (ssl).

The main class has the initialization of sockets and streams:

server main class:

```
public static void main(String[] arstring) {
            DataOutputStream out = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = null;
    SSLSocket sslsocket = null;
 ...
```

client main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader console;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    SSLSocket sslsocket = null;
  ...
```

I've create the respective sockets and streams in each class:

server sockets and streams:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory
                    .getDefault();
            sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory
                    .createServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server: listening on port: " + port + "\n");
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection...." + "\n");
            sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
            connected = true;
            System.out.println("Connection accepted \n");

            InputStream inputstreamconsola = System.in;
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreaderconsola = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputstreamconsola);
            BufferedReader bufferedreaderconsola = new BufferedReader(
                    inputstreamreaderconsola);

            in = new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
```

client sockets and streams:

```
 SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
          sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("localhost", 9999);
          in = new DataInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
          out = new DataOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
```

The problem I'm having is when I want to pass a byte [] from server to client, the byte [] has the correct value in the server but it reaches the client with null value.
Note: When I use the readUTF () and writeUTF () to pass strings, the values ​​sent are received correctly

the "error" occurs in this situation:

server:

```
     byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[(int) 8];
     nonce = System.currentTimeMillis();
     nonceBytes = longToByteArray(nonce);

    System.out.print("\nNonce gerado: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
         System.out.print(getHexString(nonceBytes[i]));
    System.out.print("\n");
            out.writeUTF("pass#");
    out.write(nonceBytes, (int) 0, nonceBytes.length); VALUE HERE IS CORRECT
```

client:

```
                byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[(int) 8];
                int nbytes = 0;

                // read the nonce sent by server
                try {
                    nbytes = in.read(nonceBytes); !!nonceBytes gets the null value instead of the value passed by the server!!
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Read: " + e.getMessage());
                    readInput = false;
                    break;
                }
```

I'd like to understand the reason why I can not send the byte [] by method out.write () and gets it in the client through the method in.read ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the result returned by `read().` You can't assume it fills the buffer. In this case you should probably be using `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Note that this problem has nothing to do with SSL whatsoever.

Comment: but the result returned by read() is saved into nbytes on client and after used. what i don't understand is the cause of the nonceBytes get the null as result from write() in server.

Comment: Your suggestion worked EJP, but i would like to understand why read() does not work .. 
Anyway thank you very much
Best regards

Comment: It does work. It just doesn't do what you think it does. It isn't the same thing. See the Javadoc. It doesn't say anywhere that it fills the buffer. On the contrary, it goes to some length to explain that it may not.

Comment: Hum.. ok i saw the javadoc and i think i get it. Thank you again EJP.